# React-native-barcode-builder usage in android

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

In my react-native project I'd like to generate barcode from given value. I found react-native-barcode-builder but I don't know how to use this library in android correctly. I've already install by `npm install --save react-native-barcode-builder` but when I want to import library in project I have following error:

> undefined is not an object (evaluating 'undefined.hex')

I think I should link this library by `react-native link` but it doesn't change anything. Every sample is for Xcode, but I developing on Windows in WebStorm. Can anyone tell me how to correctly use this library?

This is my code:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import Barcode from 'react-native-barcode-builder'
import Dimensions from 'Dimensions';
import {
    StyleSheet,
    View,
    Image
} from 'react-native';

const DEVICE_WIDTH = Dimensions.get('window').width;
const DEVICE_HEIGHT = Dimensions.get('window').height;

class CardDetailsScreen extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <Image source={this.props.imageSource} style={styles.image}/>
                <Barcode value="Hello world" format="EAN-13"/>
            </View>
        )
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
    },
    image: {
        width: DEVICE_WIDTH,
        height: 250,
    }
});

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        card: state.card
    };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        getCardData() {
            console.log('test');
        }
    }
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(CardDetailsScreen);
```

Comment: Do you think this library work with react-native ?

Comment: I apologize, I did not look closely at that library which I realize now is for node. I was just trying to show you there are other libraries out there. I suggest you find a library that gives you the information you need. Can you try and run your current code on IOS and see if it works? If it does work on IOS and you still have a problem on Android, I think it is safe to assume the problem is it does not work with Android.

Comment: I think if in readme on github author placed screen with working library on Android so it should work. Currently I can't run my code on iOS..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you've got the answer: https://devhub.io/repos/wonsikin-react-native-barcode-builder

Before use react-native-barcode-builder run: `npm install react-native-svg --save && react-native link react-native-svg` and it should works.

Comment: Thank you! It works almost correctly because when I run app on simulator it crash, but on real device it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to test a library that creates EAN13 natively you may try [react-native-barcode-creator](https://github.com/VittoriDavide/react-native-barcode-creator):

```
npm install react-native-barcode-creator && cd ios && pod install
```